# cannnot save the result of parse query in an android variabe

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am currently using Parse.com's API for an android application. I want to retreive an array from parse and save it as a list to work with later. but tha problem is when i'm out of the query my list turnes empty. can u help me?

```html
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        String userId= currentUser.getObjectId();
        final ParseQuery<ParseObject> pQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Friendship");
        pQuery.whereEqualTo("user", userId);
        pQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                if (e==null) {
                    if (list.size()>0) {
                        ParseObject p = list.get(0);
                        if (p.getList("friendsList")!=null) {
                            list11 =  p.getList("friendsList");
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Posted With Success  "+ list11.get(2).toString(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                "Posted With Success  "+list11.get(1).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

the first Toast is working but the second one gives me a NullPointerException.

Comment: Throw the list back to a method on the activity? It's now a local variable by the looks of it.

Comment: actually i'm using a Fragment, i have defined list11 as a global variable and then i have tryed to fill it with the result of the query. i did not succed :( i triyed to put this code every where ( on the on create method, on the RemoteDataTask ...)  List<String> list11 =  new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: Maybe it's your data then, you are calling the second position of your array but is it guaranteed to be filled?

Comment: i call it just in order to guaranty that the informations are here. what i want to do is to retrieve a list of objectId of my friends. Then, i will try to extract their relative data from the User class to a listview with a load more method. the problem here is that i have to do this query more than once in my fragment.

Comment: Crazy idea, since it's a global you might be accidentally replacing the array somewhere? You should not be using non-static+final global variables anyway, they are pretty much untestable since everything modifies them.

Comment: i don't know :( . i even tried to test this code alone, so there is no replacement anywhere. it is really strange. also i did not define the list11 as final or static

Answer (score 1):

You can only put second Toast in done method like this:-

```
   @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e==null) {
                if (list.size()>0) {
                    ParseObject p = list.get(0);
                    if (p.getList("friendsList")!=null) {
                        list11 =  p.getList("friendsList");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                "Posted With Success  "+ list11.get(2).toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                "Posted With Success  "+list11.get(1).toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Because findInBackground method start a new background thread.when you show second toast then list11 may be empty. Due to this it throws a NullPointerException

Comment: you mean that list11 does not lose data after the query and the problem is cosed by this story about threads ! ok thx a lot, i will try to reuse the list11 and tell u about the result